# Acceptability of relative constructions that include relativized pronouns, e.g. "the man who I wasn't sure where he had gone"

Tags: grammaticality, formality, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

In informal spoken English, one encounters sentences like this:

> ?That's the man who I wasn't sure where he had gone.

This construction doesn't strike me as quite right because it sentence includes not only the relative pronoun *who* but also the relativized pronoun *he*. In more typical relative phrases, the relativized element is deleted: _That's the man who was lost, not **That's the man who he was lost*. In *who I wasn't sure where he had gone*, though, the relativized pronoun is in a nested relative clause introduced by *where*, which inhibits the deletion: **That's the man who I wasn't sure where had gone* doesn't work. If the nested relative clause is introduced by *that*, one can't delete the relativized element and preserve *that*: *That's the man who I thought was lost* or ?*That's the man who I thought (that) he was lost*, but not **That's the man who I thought that was lost*. But *where*, like most subordinators but unlike *that*, cannot be omitted when it introduces a relative phrase.

There's often no good alternative to these constructions, though. My ?*who I wasn't sure where he had gone* example might be recast as *That's the man whose whereabouts I wasn't sure of*, but this means something subtly different and requires turning the simple verb *gone* into the clunkier *whereabouts*. (Many alternatives to these constructions require changing the secondary relative clauses into verb nominalizations, similarly, and any good style manual warns against overuse of verb nominalizations.)

So, two questions: (1) Are constructions that repeat relativized elements in relative phrases ever acceptable in formal writing? (2) If not, am I missing a good standard method of recasting these constructions as something unambiguously grammatical?

Comment: What you are encountering here are known as Island constraints. The constraint you are noticing here is listed as 3.1 [in these notes on Island Constraints](https://msu.edu/course/lin/434/PSets/island-constraints.pdf)

Comment: What makes you think that the pronoun "he" is a relativized element and not simply a pro-form. Isn't it just an anaphor, and not an 'R'?

Comment: Your sentence is not wrong, but pretty, it's not. Such constructions leave the reader to go back and reread, spending time that no one has to spare on figuring out exactly what it means. A step better, because it is simpler: _That's the man who left me wondering where he went._

Comment: @Yosef Baskin Do I say here 'Oh yes it is wrong'?

Comment: @E - No, you do not say 'Oh yes, it is wrong.' Did I say you did? Sorry. Miscommunication? I was saying that the original sentence is clumsy, that's all.

Comment: It's more than clumsy; it's ungrammatical, for reasons explained in the duplicate link.